# How many DataViews to create?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, dataview

I have created a DataView sorted on 3 columns of a DataTable.

```
dv1 = new DataView(tbl1, null, "Col1, Col2, Col3", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

In one part of the code, I need to find rows based on all the 3 columns, whereas in another part of the code, I need to find rows based on the 1st 2 columns.

Do I have to create as many DataViews as the combination of the number of columns based on which I want to find rows?

If I try to search by making the 3rd column null, like this:

```
drv1 = dv1.FindRows(new object[] { col1Val, col2Val, null });
```

then .NET tries to match rows having null value in the 3rd column, whereas what I want is all rows based on 1st 2 columns' values irrespective of value in 3rd column.

Thanks.

Comment: If the code is finished with the current view (i.e. you do not need have its filtered results displayed), then you do not need to create a new instance.  Just reconfigure it via its 'Table`, 'RowFilter', `'Sort', and `RowStateFilter` properties.

Comment: I am not displaying the results anywhere. The code is loading data from a lot of Excel sheets into datatables and processing them.